# How can I update page title in my setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a title with a flask jinja2 input. I want to update the title along with some div tags.
I update the div tags with setInterval and jquery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
setInterval(timingLoad, 15000);
function timingLoad() {
$.get().done(doc => {
  $("#main").html($(" #main", doc))
  $("#count").html($(" #count", doc))
});
}
}); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>
```

My title looks like this:

```
<title id="online_count">{% block title %} ({{online_num}}) Online{% endblock %} </title>
```

How can I in the setInterval function have the title refresh as well?
Adding `$("#online_count").html($(" #online_count", doc))` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not working because you are not setting a string:

`$("#online_count").html($(" #online_count", doc))` might just be a jQuery element. Try this instead:

`$("#online_count").html($(" #online_count", doc).html())`